# Background image on the stackexchange site is quite big

Tags: discussion, design, optimization

Is there a reason the background image *[bg-hatchlines.png](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/bg-hatchlines.png)* on the main stackexchange site is `148x38` in size?

It looks like it could be `5x38` at a minimum or at least half the size, keeping the same effect the image gives now. Wouldn't this save some bandwidth for the site?

Here's the image:
[image]

And the minimum size of the same image:
[image]

Comment: For reference: 7.2Kb compared with 0.8Kb

Comment: Most likely for hysterical raisins; it once contained more detail but it was never recropped when the background changed, perhaps?

Comment: Just as an aside: once an image has been cached, then even when forcing a refresh most browsers do not actually get the image again. Instead, most browsers will send a request with an `If-Modified-Since` (or `If-None-Match`) header, to ask the server if the image has changed. Assuming the server will then respond with `304 Not Modified`, that request and its response are the same size for both images.